# OpenUDID is public or private for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, udid

Hi I developing one application for ios 4 onwards.In ios4 iam  using uniqueIdentifer.But this one is deprecated in ios5.So now i want to use OpenUDID for ios5.If i use this one my application is approve or not by apple.And OpenUDID supports which versions.

Comment: "Will my app be approved by Apple" can **only** be answered by Apple, nobody else. - "And OpenUDID supports which versions." - read its documentation and you'll know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. you can use **OpenUDID**.

> OpenUDID is a drop-in replacement for the deprecated uniqueIdentifier
>   property of the UIDevice class on iOS (a.k.a. UDID) and otherwise is
>   an industry-friendly equivalent for iOS and Android, and most recently
>   Windows C# and Silverlight (see links above).

Here is the link:

[OpenUDID](https://github.com/xaviermichel/OpenUDID)

You app will not be rejected because of OpenUDID.
OpenUDID supports from version 5